# Two correct answers exactly the same, accept one but divide the awarded reputation points?

Tags: discussion

On a few occasions I've asked a question and received two identical answers at the same time. Immediately I face the moral dilemma of choosing which one to accept. I feel bad choosing one over the other, and when it's happened it's been between a dedicated member with 10s of thousands of reputation points, and a new user with 100-400 reputation points, etc.

I've been accepting the answers of the dedicated members, but I feel maybe it'd be better for the future of the community if newer members had their answers accepted.

It is probably a silly question, and you don't feel as bad as I do about it, but what if you could accept an answer, but divide the awarded reputation points equally between two users?

Comment: That'd be 7.5 points to each user..

Comment: Just accept one and upvote the other, i'm pretty sure the OP of the upvoted question could stand the blow

Comment: Flip a coin please.  Blame the coin.

Comment: If possible, accept the one that was answered first. If they were answered on the same minute and enough time passes and you can't see who posted first, accept the one with the post upvotes. If both have the same amount of upvotes(or downvotes or n ovotes at all), accept the one with the most detailed explanation

Comment: Side note: to avoid such cases when people instantly provide answers you may want to search for existing questions (and at very least show results of your research). For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251920/jquery-invalid-left-hand-side-error is very common error with multiple answers (I've voted as duplicate of one that had some reasonable number of votes, plus I've added actual explanation there). Also note that you are asking about error and really you are looking for some other duplicate ("set value" there...)

Comment: FWIW users with a lot of rep tend to care less about getting *more* rep, while it could be more important to the new user as it leads to new privileges. Please don't automatically choose an answer over another just because it was posted by a user with more rep.

Answer (score 11):

Don't accept an answer based on the user, or their rep, or who answered first. Vote based on your opinion of the quality of the answers. They're probably not really *identical*. One example from your questions is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410746/length-of-p-element-changing-position-of-parent) with two similar answers from users with different rep levels like you described. The one that you accepted is actually a better answer, in my opinion, because it includes a little more explanation instead of just telling you to change something.

If you think the other answer is helpful, then upvote it too, but you don't need to feel guilty for accepting one answer over another. It's your prerogative as the asker, and anyone who answers should understand and accept that it's possible for another answer to be accepted even if theirs is also correct.

If they really are virtually identical (no differences except variable names or minor details like that) and answered at almost the same time, then it really doesn't matter which one you accept or who gets the rep.

Comment: That's a good answer, thank you :) I think this question has been badly recieved becuase I included the request tag which I shouldn't have. It wasn't a request that I actually thought would be implemented, more of a discussion topic.

Comment: You're probably right. Voting on feature-request questions indicates agreement/disagreement with the feature request, rather than whether or not people think the discussion is worthwhile.